# a big number of Principal components while using PCA

Tags: pca

I'm new to PCA, I have a dataset of 64 features and I am trying to get the most important features using PCA. When running PCA that explains 90% of the variance in my dataset I am getting about 40 principal components, and my question is, how can I get the feature importance based on all these principal components ?[in the pic1 shown the number of principal components that explains 90% of the variance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp6uQ.png)
should I sum the values of all principal components for each feature and then sort it in descending order ?

Answer (score 0):

just run a regression model and check values of the importance statistics associated with each feature. Check out [this article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-feature-importance-with-python/) for discussion of feature importance.